# FreeTTS java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, speech, freetts

I am trying to make a text to speech program, but I always get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at FreeTTS.main(FreeTTS.java:7)
```

Here is my code:

```
import com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice;
import com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager;
public class FreeTTS {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        VoiceManager vm = VoiceManager.getInstance();
        Voice voice = vm.getVoice("kevin16");
        voice.allocate();
        voice.speak("Hello World!");
        voice.deallocate();
    }
}
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Which line is line 7?

Answer (score 1):

```
vm.getVoice("kevin16")
```

is returning `null`.  From the Javadoc:

> Returns: the Voice that has the same name as voiceName if one exists, else null

Ergo, voice "kevin16" was not found.